# expression/idiom for a useless task?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I kept thinking of a flightless task, which I don't think is an actual expression.
I am looking for a manner of speaking that captures the idea of shielding a group of people from a set of facts that they have already been confronted with.

Comment: Please provide more detail. Do you want a noun, a verb, something else? What do you mean by "shielding a group of people from a set of facts that they have already been confronted with"? Good facts or bad facts, scary facts or enlightening facts? Trying to keep people in the dark, or trying to hide something unpleasant from them? And is it completely useless (e.g. they're certain to find out) or just too late (could have been avoided)?

Comment: @Marc has had a valiant attempt at answering this question, but please see the help available for [phrase-request](/tags/phrase-requests/info) questions.

Comment: You're probably thinking of [*a **fruitless** task*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+fruitless+task%2Ca+thankless+task&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) Which was much more common a couple of centuries ago, but I wouldn't say it's exactly "dated". Note that closely-related ***thankless** task* hasn't suffered such a significant decline in currency.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a manner of speaking that captures the idea of shielding a group of people from a set of facts that they have already been confronted with.

It sounds as though you're trying to shield those people [*ex post facto*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ex%20post%20facto). (This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it's hard to tell without a sample sentence or some other context.)

You may also be looking for an expression such as ["the horse has left the barn"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+horse+has+(already)+left+the+barn) or ["that ship has sailed"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/that+ship+has+sailed). (Again, I can't really tell whether these directly address your particular situation. Please clarify if possible.)